# Foreign key is null when NH save the childs collection

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I try to map NHibernate to an existing database structure. Unfortunately **I can not change the existing structure**.

First I'll give some background and then explain the problem itself

Relational analysis is quite simple:
[image]

**Log** is the main Entity. he has one-to-one relationship with **Form**.
the foreign key is **FormID**.

Buyer & Seller are collection of the form entity.
The application should save the **form entity together with the buyers and the sellers**.

The problem is the primary key consisting of the Buyer & Seller entity.
The key composite from ForegineKey- **FormID** and an intenal ordering int number- **tdNum**

This is reflected in the following form FNH mapping

```
public class FormLogMap : ClassMap<FormLog>
{
    public FormLogMap()
    {
        Table("BillOfSaleLog");

        Id(x => x.FormId).Column("FormID").GeneratedBy.Native();
        ....
        ....
        References<Form>(x => x.Form, "FormID").LazyLoad().ReadOnly();
    }
}

public class FormMap : ClassMap<Form>
{
    public FormMap()
    {

    Table("BillOfSaleForm");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("FormID").GeneratedBy.Foreign("Log");
        ...
        ...

        HasOne<FormLog>(x => x.Log).Cascade.All();

        HasMany(x => x.Buyers).KeyColumn("FormID").Inverse().Cascade.All();

        HasMany(x => x.Sellers).KeyColumn("FormID").Inverse().Cascade.All();
    }
}


public class BuyerMap : ClassMap<Buyer>
{
    public BuyerMap()
    {

        Table("BillOfSaleBuyer");

        CompositeId()
                    .KeyReference(x => x.Form, "FormID")
                    .KeyProperty(x => x.InnerOrderId, "tdNum1");

         ....
         ....
    }
}

Seller is exectly the same
```

**The problem occurs when I try to save the entity by the Edit Action**
I'm using MVC to get the user data and make it an object.
The binding works fine and makes the object along with the collections.

But when I save an entity receive the following error:
[image]

I expect NHibernate be smart enough to set the Buyer & Seller foreign keys.
But in fact they remain without value.

The problem can be solved by setting foreign keys manually 
as the following code:

```
        //i have to set the form proerty in the childs
        //without of the lines NH will try to save the childs it with FormID = null
        foreach (var buyer in form.Buyers) { buyer.Form = form; }
        foreach (var seller in form.Sellers) { seller.Form = form; }
```

**But I'm looking for an elegant and correct solution**

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the code for adding a Buyer or Seller to a Form but it should look like this:

```
form.Buyers.Add(buyer);
buyer.Form = form;
```

Because Form is the inverse side of the relationships, you have to set the reference to Form on the many side. You should do this anyway so that the in-memory objects are correct. If the Buyer and Seller objects are already persistent in the same ISession than that should work.

Comment: I mentioned above that the form object I get through databinding from an edit view. I do not create the form object instance by code that referance between the objects its little problem. Another option is in addition to information of the seller / buyer in the view also include the foreign key of the form parent.  It's simple to get around the problem. Too bad ..

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420498/how-to-cascade-save-with-compositeid-in-nhibernate/1584335) related question, HHibernate does not support cascade working with a composite key (as you have in `BuyerMap`). One of the answers does contain a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420498/how-to-cascade-save-with-compositeid-in-nhibernate/1584335#1584335) to workaround this, but you will end up with a redundant column.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I understand the suggested solution but it requires a change in tabular schem.
I'll take my proposed solution above.

It is understandable that the ability to map clumsy relational structure is problematic